# Avoid temp variables with constructing items to add to a list

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, lambda

Java 8 has so many features that allow you to avoid temp variables and functions, it seems that there has to be a way to avoid using these temp vars to create this list:

```
List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
Phone p1 = new Phone();
p1.setNumber(this.mainPhoneNumber);
p1.setExtension(this.mainPhoneExt);
p1.setType(this.mainPhoneDesc);
phones.add(p1);
Phone p2 = new Phone();
p2.setNumber(this.secondaryPhoneNumberOne);
p2.setExtension(this.secondaryPhoneExtOne);
p2.setType(this.secondaryPhoneDescOne);
phones.add(p2);
Phone p3 = new Phone();
p3.setNumber(this.secondaryPhoneNumberTwo);
p3.setExtension(this.secondaryPhoneExtTwo);
p3.setType(this.secondaryPhoneDescTwo);
phones.add(p3);
```

I have a bunch of ugly member variables that need to be collated into a list.  The `Phone` object does not have a nice constructor, and I cannot change it.

How can I make this list from member variables without defining the three temp objects `p1, p2, p3`?

Comment: You can create a constructor for `Phone` class taking the 3 arguments. If there are many fields in the `Phone` class you can use the [`builder pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) too for help for creating the Phone's objects.

Comment: To cut out the repeated `add()` statements, you'll need Java 9's `List.of()` or Guava's `ImmutableList.of()`.

Comment: `List<Phone> phones = Arrays.asList(p1, p2, p3)` can also be used if you are not using java 9.

Comment: If `Phone` was `final`, but implemented an interface, you could use `reflect.Proxy` - with or (tedious, and not against 3rd party code) without an instance of the original `Phone` class. (I guess I would be put off by having to repeat the setter invocations much more than by having otherwise useless variables (or an array).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can modify `Phone` to make the setters chainable, you could aim for this:

```
phones.add(
    new Phone()
        .setNumber(this.mainPhoneNumber)
        .setExtension(this.mainPhoneExt)
        .setType(this.mainPhoneDesc)
);
```

If that's not possible, you can create an external builder class. Using it would look like:

```
phones.add(
    new PhoneBuilder()
        .number(this.mainPhoneNumber)
        .extension(this.mainPhoneExt)
        .type(this.mainPhoneDesc)
    .build()
);
```

Implementing a builder class is tedious, but straightforward. You store all of the field values in member variables and then create the actual `Phone` object when `build()` is called. You'll find yourself duplicating a lot of `Phone`'s method names. Don't worry about it, that's normal.

Comment: I can't change the base `Phone` class, but I can make a new private builder class.  It doesn't really save me any lines of code, but it makes me feel much better to not have even a small amount of copy/pasta .

Answer (score 3):

Could you do something like this?

```
public Phone phoneMaker(int number, int ext, string description) {
    Phone p = new Phone();
    p.setNumber(number);
    p.setExtension(ext);
    p.setType(description);
    return p;
}
```

```java
List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
phones.add(phoneMaker(this.mainPhoneNumber, this.mainPhoneExt, this.mainPhoneDesc));
```

Answer (score 0):

John Kugelman and Teo has showed you some of the various possibilities.

You could avoid (explicit) temp vars by

```
List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
phones.add(new Phone());  // get(0)
phones.add(new Phone());  // get(1)
phones.add(new Phone());  // get(2)

phones.get(0).setNumber(this.mainPhoneNumber);
phones.get(0).setExtension(this.mainPhoneExt);
phones.get(0).setType(this.mainPhoneDesc);

phones.get(1).setNumber(this.mainPhoneNumberOne);
phones.get(1).setExtension(this.mainPhoneExtOne);
phones.get(1).setType(this.mainPhoneDescOne);

phones.get(2).setNumber(this.mainPhoneNumberTwo);
phones.get(2).setExtension(this.mainPhoneExtTwo);
phones.get(2).setType(this.mainPhoneDescTwo);
```

An other way is to use anonymous classes. That looks like

```
List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<>();
phones.add(new Phone() {   // class
    {                      // initializer  (no this)
         setNumber(mainPhoneNumber);
         setExtension(mainPhoneExt);
         setType(mainPhoneDesc);
    }
});
phones.add(new Phone() {
    {
         setNumber(mainPhoneNumberOne);
         setExtension(mainPhoneExtOne);
         setType(mainPhoneDescOne);
    }
});
```

WARNING: your this does not work inside an initializer.

As you can see, there are a lot possibilities with different flavours and pro and cons.

---

By the way, to implement chainable setters or fluent interfaces, just return always this. Here is an example

```
class X {
    private T1 p1;
    private T2 p2;

    public X setter1 (T1 p1) {
       this.p1 = p1;
       return this;
    }

    public X setter2 (T2 p2) {
       this.p2 = p2;
       return this;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what "anonymous classes" are.  Using that "`new foo() {setSomething()}`" syntax creates a new subclass of `foo()`, not a new instance with an anonymous variable.